# How to remove ^M in emacs

Tags: emacs, line-breaks, carriage-return, line-endings, eol

How can I remove `^M` characters in Emacs?

It doesn't work using `dos2unix filename` or `unix2dos filename`.

Normally I cannot see any `^M` characters, but this is what came out when using the command `cat -A filename` :

Please explain it in plain words... and in detail...

```
cat -A ABC.sh
#!/bin/csh -f^M$
^M$
^M$
set input = `ls -1 *.py`^M$
echo $input^M$
```

Comment: `dos2unix` *should* convert that. What output does it give you?

Answer (score 26):

[Searched for a duplicate, but didn't find one about replacing (instead of preventing etc.). If there is one then this one or that one should be *closed*.]

In Emacs, visit the file that has the `^M` chars.  Go to the beginning of the file (`M-<`), then:

```
M-x replace-string RET C-q C-m RET RET
```

That is, at the prompt for what to replace, use `Control` + `q` then `Control` + `m`, then `Enter`. At the prompt for what to replace it with, just hit `Enter` (replace it with nothing).

Comment: Thanks. This worked fine, however there must be a `RET` between `replace-string` and `C-q`

Comment: this actually didn't work for me, the command was identified correctly replacing ^M with "", but 0 occurrences were replaced

Comment: @AidenCullo: Does your buffer actually contain `^M` chars? What does `C-s C-q C-m` show you?

Answer (score 8):

I've been using this

```
(defun delete-carrage-returns ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char 0)
    (while (search-forward "\r" nil :noerror)
      (replace-match ""))))
```

I'm sure there is a better way, but this works well enough that I stopped looking.

Comment: This helps when ^M gets pasted form clipboard. Then, other systems wiill not work.